# UIWebView doesn't loadRequest second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

From firstViewController I send a url to load on secondViewController.  The url loads correctly. They, I press cancel button to go back to firstViewController:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then again if I come back to secondViewController from firstViewController, I see a blank space with horizontal scrollbar.

I've used the following code to load url:

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.apple.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

I've implemented webview delegate methods and they are being called without any problem. for example following methods are called:

```
– webViewDidStartLoad:
– webViewDidFinishLoad:
```

Even there is no error to load and I've printed html source codes in -webViewDidFinishLoad and it Logged right codes.

My device iOS version is: iOS 9.3.2

**Update:** 
The same app works well on my simulator. But doesn't work on real device.

Comment: show more relevant code of the class and also tell how are you presenting the controller

Comment: I'm presenting the controller as segue (show).

Comment: and the class code ?

Comment: I facing the same issue, did you solve the issue?